# Controlling Instruments using applescript

Tags: applescript

Is that possible to control or automate apple’s Instruments through applescript? 
If Yes, pls let me know its procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

YES!  I just did that this week.

Here is a sample script that lets you target the Simulator.  To target Instruments, you would have to turn on GUI scripting and go through that interface.  I used the UI Browser to point out to me which control I needed to bring into scope.

This script sends a return to text field 1 in window 1 of the app running in the Simulator.  You would use a similar approach to script Instruments.

```
on run
    main()
end run

on main()
    tell application "System Events"
        set myWindow to get window 1 of application process "iOS Simulator"
        set myField to text field 1 of myWindow
    end tell

    set iterations to 0
    repeat while true
        activate application "iPhone Simulator"
        set iterations to iterations + 1
        log iterations
        tell application "System Events"
            click myField
            keystroke return
        end tell
        delay 10
    end repeat
end main
```

Comment: Not sure I get this in regard to Instruments.  Are you expecting Instruments to be attached to the iPhone Simulator, or something?

Answer (score 0):

Instruments is not scriptable with Applescript.

Comment: If we could automate most of the mac's apps through applescript, then why we r unable to automate Instruments alone. Is there any specific reason behind it?. We are analysing for the long time, but we are yet to get the ways for it.

Comment: The decision to make an application scriptable is entirely at the discretion of the developer, in this case Apple. For reasons only known to them, their support of Applescript in their own apps has declined over the years.

Comment: Thank you, Philip, for your clarification. Yes, you are correct as We analysed this when we were trying to add "Instruments" into applescript editor's library, we have got an error as "it is not scriptable".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the task you are trying to perform - some things in instruments can indeed be scripted. If you could provide a little more context then maybe we can help...